# Preparing data for TfidfVectorizer use (scikitlearn)

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am trying to use TfIdfVectorizer of sklearn. I am having trouble because my input is probably not matching TfIdfVectorizer needs. I have a bunch of JSONs I loaded and appended into a list, and I now want that to be the corpus for TfIdfVectorizer use.

The code:

```
import json
import pandas
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

train=pandas.read_csv("train.tsv",  sep='\t')
documents=[]

for i,row in train.iterrows():
        data = json.loads(row['boilerplate'].lower()) 
        documents.append(data['body'])
vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
idf = vectorizer.idf_
print dict(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), idf))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-56-94a6b95b0745>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Guinea Pig/Downloads/try.py', wdir='C:/Users/Guinea Pig/Downloads')

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 585, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Guinea Pig/Downloads/try.py", line 19, in <module>
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1219, in fit_transform
    X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 780, in fit_transform
    vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, self.fixed_vocabulary)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 715, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 229, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 195, in <lambda>
    return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I am getting that the documents array consists of Unicode objects, and not string objects, but I can't seem to solve this issue. ant ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I used:

```
str_docs=[]
for item in documents:
    str_docs.append(documents[i].encode('utf-8'))
```

As an addition